# Power BI - When changing a column type with Google Analytics, all the column type change

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have some thing like :

```
#"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(#"12345678", { [... some custom dimensions ...], {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:date", {"ga:date"}, {"Date"}}, {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:source", {"ga:source"}, {"Source"}}, {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Avg. Time on Page", "ga:avgTimeOnPage"}, {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Pageviews", "gaSmiley Tongueageviews"}, {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Time on Page", "ga:timeOnPage"}}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes( #"Added Items",{{"[... a column name ...]", type date}})
in
#"Changed Type"
```

The column was a text column, and I change it to Date, all the other column are change to Text, so I lose every single type except the new one.

Like "Time on Page" or "Pageviews" are now Text Column.

Any idea why?

Same thing happen when I add a new column, all the other columns are transform to Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug, on Power BI Forum :

I can reproduce the issue in my environment. I already reported this issue internally, will update here once I get any feedback.Smiley Happy

Regards